# Does monkey patching in Python affect direct imports?

Tags: python, import, namespaces, monkeypatching

If I monkey patch a module:

```
# mokeypatch.py
import other_module

def replacement(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

other_module.some_func = replacement
```

Will this affect a module that imports `some_func` directly, or will it depend on the order of imports? If a third module is like this:

```
# third_module.py
from other_module import some_func
```

First, this code is run, then our monkey patch. Will `third_module.some_func` be the old one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will point to the old function.

When doing `from mod import func` inside `mod2`, `func` will be bound in scope of `mod2`.
Monkeypatching `mod.func` will bind `mod.func` to the new function but neither `mod` nor `mod.func` know that `mod2.func` even exist - and even if they did (internally they might know it somewhere) they couldn't know if it should be replaced or now.

A practical example why rebinding the imported name would be problematic is this:

```
# monkeypatch.py
import other_module
from other_module import func as orig_func
def replacement():
    do_stuff()
    orig_func()
    do_stuff()
other_module.func = replacement
```

If it was rebound, you'd now have infinite recursion and no way to call the original function.

Comment: Yes, I had this recursion gotcha a few times. :)

Comment: but if the monkey patch code runs first, would third_module point to the new func?

Comment: @JamesLin Yes it will